# I can't understand visual studio tabs have changed

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

Here, when a view is created with *TextViewCreated*, I do some operations there, the editor works without a problem when a single file is open, but because I cannot understand that there are different files when I open two files, or because I have no information when they change, it performs incorrectly. How can tell when switching files visual studio?

```cs
    [Export(typeof(IWpfTextViewCreationListener))]
    [ContentType("text")]
    [TextViewRole(PredefinedTextViewRoles.Document)]
    internal sealed class EditorListener : IWpfTextViewCreationListener
    {
        [Import] private readonly IAsyncCompletionBroker _completionBroker = null;
        [Import] private readonly IEditorOperationsFactoryService _editorOperationsFactory = null;

        private ParenthesesManager Manager { get; set; }
        private IWpfTextView TextView { get; set; }
        private IEditorOperations EditorOperations { get; set; }

        public void TextViewCreated(IWpfTextView textView)
        {
            TextView = textView;
            EditorOperations = _editorOperationsFactory.GetEditorOperations(textView);
            if (_completionBroker != null)
            {
                _completionBroker.CompletionTriggered += CompletionBroker_CompletionTriggered;
            }

            Manager = new ParenthesesManager(EditorOperations, TextView);
        }

        private void CompletionBroker_CompletionTriggered(object sender, CompletionTriggeredEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            eventArgs.CompletionSession.ItemCommitted += CompletionSession_ItemCommitted;

            EditorOperations = _editorOperationsFactory.GetEditorOperations(eventArgs.TextView);
            Manager.TextView = TextView;
            Manager.EditorOperations = EditorOperations;
        }

        private void CompletionSession_ItemCommitted(object sender, CompletionItemEventArgs itemEventArgs)
        {
            Manager.Run(itemEventArgs);
            var session = _completionBroker.GetSession(TextView);
            session.ItemCommitted -= CompletionSession_ItemCommitted;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Different files open in different tabs, is that what you don't understand?

Comment: Actually I understand when it first opened, but I can't understand when browsing through open tabs.

Comment: You can try to use [TextBuffer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.text.editor.itextview.textbuffer?view=visualstudiosdk-2019#Microsoft_VisualStudio_Text_Editor_ITextView_TextBuffer) to confirm if the file has been read before opening it